# Maven Build Issues

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am new to maven and created a simple Maven Project with hello world. When I try to run Maven Project it says: -

[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format : or :[:]:. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]

I saw from the internet that you need to give a goal. I went through a video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H7qKpz17gfU

Here he writes tomcatrun as goal. When I do that, it gives me the same error.

I tried to write deploy and check. It gave me an error: -
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project newwebapps: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]

Where am I going wrong? Please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be `tomcat:run` , mind the colon.